# Combine different columns from 2 different queries into one resultset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are many similar questions but not exactly what I wanted to I'm reserved to asking a question so forgive me if this is a duplicate as I couldn't find precisely what I wanted.

I have a query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.Col1, t1.Col2, <need_to_append_here> 
FROM t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 
ON t1.Id = t2.Id 
WHERE t1.Id = 'x'
ORDER BY t2.Col2 DESC
```

Where you see **need_to_append_here**, I need a completely different sql to be appended to the result so I get 4 columns in the result set:

```
SELECT t3.Col3, t3.Col4 FROM t3 WHERE t3.Id = 'z'
```

I should see one row with Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4

**UPDATE**
I was able to get it to work but with a single column from the 2nd query by doing something like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 t1.Col1, t2.Col2, (SELECT t3.Col3..) Col3
FROM ....
```

But I'm unable to include 2 columns in the 2nd select

Comment: can't just add `JOIN t3 ON t3.Id = 'z'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just JOIN (or LEFT JOIN) since you're doing TOP 1

```
SELECT TOP 1
        t1.Col1,
        t1.Col2,
        t3.Col3,
        t3.Col4
FROM    t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t3.Id = 'z'
WHERE   t1.Id = 'x'
ORDER BY t2.Col2 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If the additional query simply returns one row, you can use a `CROSS JOIN` to append it to your original query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t3.Col3, t3.Col4
FROM t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id 
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT t3.Col3, t3.Col4 
   FROM t3 
   WHERE t3.Id = 'z') AS t3(Col3, Col4)
WHERE t1.Id = 'x'
ORDER BY t2.Col2 DESC
```

Comment: your answer works but the other answer with a LEFT JOIN seems simpler. Wish I could give you both credit. Thank you very much though

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as example:

```
select t1.ks, t1.[# Tasks], coalesce(t2.[# Late], 0) as [# Late]
from 
    (SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks) t1
left join
    (SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table WHERE Age > Palt GROUP BY ks) t2
on
    t1.ks = t2.ks
```